# Cloudformation stacks, then how can I find the reason or log

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

When deploying from template,

This service is stack as `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`

```
ServiceD69D759B arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:6781002281XX:service/AdminCluster/CdkFargateStack-ServiceD69D759B-sm274jjTfbP7   AWS::ECS::Service   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated -
```

However I have no idea where to start.

This docker image receive the access from 8011, so in local

it works in local like this

```
docker run -p 8011:8011 -it st_admin_site:latest
```

I check CloudWatch but can't find the log.

This is my cdk command

```
constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "SampleCluster", {
      clusterName: "AdminCluster"
    });
    const adminImage = ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('st_admin_site:latest');
    const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, "TaskDef");
  
    const container = taskDefinition.addContainer("DefaultContainer", {
      image: adminImage,
      memoryLimitMiB: 512,
      cpu: 256
    });
    container.addPortMappings({
      containerPort: 8011
    });
    const ecsService = new ecs.FargateService(this, "Service", {
      cluster,
      taskDefinition,
      desiredCount: 2
    });
    const lb = new elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "LB", {
      vpc: cluster.vpc,
      internetFacing: true
    });
    const listener = lb.addListener("Listener", { port: 80 });

    const targetGroup = listener.addTargets("ECS", {
      protocol: elb.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      port: 8011,
      targets: [ecsService]
    });
```

And it makes the template.

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "SampleClusterB4B72990": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
      "Properties": {
        "ClusterName": "AdminCluster"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Resource"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "EnableDnsHostnames": true,
        "EnableDnsSupport": true,
        "InstanceTenancy": "default",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/Resource"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1SubnetE377A512": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/18",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            0,
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Public"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Public"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1RouteTable7114D244": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation0B5402E3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1RouteTable7114D244"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1SubnetE377A512"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1DefaultRoute28A82BC4": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1RouteTable7114D244"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcIGW21649D5C"
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "SampleClusterVpcVPCGW39AFB859"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1EIPD2C3FC83": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
      "Properties": {
        "Domain": "vpc",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1/EIP"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1NATGateway715FE613": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NatGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1SubnetE377A512"
        },
        "AllocationId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1EIPD2C3FC83",
            "AllocationId"
          ]
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet1/NATGateway"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2SubnetB88D2B08": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.64.0/18",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            1,
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Public"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Public"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2RouteTable8A11EEAD": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation857BF408": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2RouteTable8A11EEAD"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2SubnetB88D2B08"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2DefaultRouteFD4087CF": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2RouteTable8A11EEAD"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcIGW21649D5C"
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "SampleClusterVpcVPCGW39AFB859"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2EIPCB2281EA": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
      "Properties": {
        "Domain": "vpc",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2/EIP"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2NATGatewayB385D543": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NatGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2SubnetB88D2B08"
        },
        "AllocationId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2EIPCB2281EA",
            "AllocationId"
          ]
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PublicSubnet2/NATGateway"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1Subnet24256A44": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.128.0/18",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            0,
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Private"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Private"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet1/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTable55080EB4": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet1/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociationBC171CD8": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTable55080EB4"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1Subnet24256A44"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet1/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1DefaultRouteB1C5B147": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1RouteTable55080EB4"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "NatGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1NATGateway715FE613"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet1/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2Subnet25DCB36D": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.192.0/18",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            1,
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-name",
            "Value": "Private"
          },
          {
            "Key": "aws-cdk:subnet-type",
            "Value": "Private"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet2/Subnet"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTable35B9289E": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet2/RouteTable"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssociationC174EB56": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTable35B9289E"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2Subnet25DCB36D"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet2/RouteTableAssociation"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2DefaultRoute74AE4D72": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2RouteTable35B9289E"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "NatGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2NATGatewayB385D543"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/PrivateSubnet2/DefaultRoute"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcIGW21649D5C": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/IGW"
      }
    },
    "SampleClusterVpcVPCGW39AFB859": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        },
        "InternetGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcIGW21649D5C"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/SampleCluster/Vpc/VPCGW"
      }
    },
    "TaskDefTaskRole1EDB4A67": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/TaskDef/TaskRole/Resource"
      }
    },
    "TaskDef54694570": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
      "Properties": {
        "ContainerDefinitions": [
          {
            "Cpu": 256,
            "Essential": true,
            "Image": "st_admin_site:latest",
            "Memory": 512,
            "Name": "DefaultContainer",
            "PortMappings": [
              {
                "ContainerPort": 8011,
                "Protocol": "tcp"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Cpu": "256",
        "Family": "CdkFargateStackTaskDef424235B4",
        "Memory": "512",
        "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
        "RequiresCompatibilities": [
          "FARGATE"
        ],
        "TaskRoleArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "TaskDefTaskRole1EDB4A67",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/TaskDef/Resource"
      }
    },
    "ServiceD69D759B": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
      "Properties": {
        "Cluster": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterB4B72990"
        },
        "DeploymentConfiguration": {
          "MaximumPercent": 200,
          "MinimumHealthyPercent": 50
        },
        "DesiredCount": 2,
        "EnableECSManagedTags": false,
        "HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds": 60,
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "LoadBalancers": [
          {
            "ContainerName": "DefaultContainer",
            "ContainerPort": 8011,
            "TargetGroupArn": {
              "Ref": "LBListenerECSGroup1D445DF5"
            }
          }
        ],
        "NetworkConfiguration": {
          "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
            "AssignPublicIp": "DISABLED",
            "SecurityGroups": [
              {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "ServiceSecurityGroupC96ED6A7",
                  "GroupId"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "Subnets": [
              {
                "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet1Subnet24256A44"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPrivateSubnet2Subnet25DCB36D"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "TaskDefinition": {
          "Ref": "TaskDef54694570"
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "LBListenerECSGroup1D445DF5",
        "LBListener49E825B4"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/Service/Service"
      }
    },
    "ServiceSecurityGroupC96ED6A7": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "CdkFargateStack/Service/SecurityGroup",
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
          {
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "Description": "Allow all outbound traffic by default",
            "IpProtocol": "-1"
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/Service/SecurityGroup/Resource"
      }
    },
    "ServiceSecurityGroupfromCdkFargateStackLBSecurityGroupF16A57958011E231ABAF": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "Description": "Load balancer to target",
        "FromPort": 8011,
        "GroupId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ServiceSecurityGroupC96ED6A7",
            "GroupId"
          ]
        },
        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LBSecurityGroup8A41EA2B",
            "GroupId"
          ]
        },
        "ToPort": 8011
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/Service/SecurityGroup/from CdkFargateStackLBSecurityGroupF16A5795:8011"
      }
    },
    "LB8A12904C": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "LoadBalancerAttributes": [
          {
            "Key": "deletion_protection.enabled",
            "Value": "false"
          }
        ],
        "Scheme": "internet-facing",
        "SecurityGroups": [
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "LBSecurityGroup8A41EA2B",
              "GroupId"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Subnets": [
          {
            "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1SubnetE377A512"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2SubnetB88D2B08"
          }
        ],
        "Type": "application"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet1DefaultRoute28A82BC4",
        "SampleClusterVpcPublicSubnet2DefaultRouteFD4087CF"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/LB/Resource"
      }
    },
    "LBSecurityGroup8A41EA2B": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Automatically created Security Group for ELB CdkFargateStackLBFC3A10CF",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "Description": "Allow from anyone on port 80",
            "FromPort": 80,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "ToPort": 80
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/LB/SecurityGroup/Resource"
      }
    },
    "LBSecurityGrouptoCdkFargateStackServiceSecurityGroupB491C33C801194A30A9B": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LBSecurityGroup8A41EA2B",
            "GroupId"
          ]
        },
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "Description": "Load balancer to target",
        "DestinationSecurityGroupId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ServiceSecurityGroupC96ED6A7",
            "GroupId"
          ]
        },
        "FromPort": 8011,
        "ToPort": 8011
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/LB/SecurityGroup/to CdkFargateStackServiceSecurityGroupB491C33C:8011"
      }
    },
    "LBListener49E825B4": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
          {
            "TargetGroupArn": {
              "Ref": "LBListenerECSGroup1D445DF5"
            },
            "Type": "forward"
          }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": {
          "Ref": "LB8A12904C"
        },
        "Port": 80,
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/LB/Listener/Resource"
      }
    },
    "LBListenerECSGroup1D445DF5": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "Port": 8011,
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "TargetGroupAttributes": [
          {
            "Key": "stickiness.enabled",
            "Value": "false"
          }
        ],
        "TargetType": "ip",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "SampleClusterVpcD1C6ABD9"
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/LB/Listener/ECSGroup/Resource"
      }
    },
    "CDKMetadata": {
      "Type": "AWS::CDK::Metadata",
      "Properties": {
        "Analytics": "v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/31Ry27CMBD8Fu7GBSr1TilFSFUVJYhr5ThbumDWkR9BKMq/184D0lbqaWdn18nMzoLPZ3w2ERc7lcVpqjDndeaEPLFAfdQgLa9XylsHhq0+aYCvwhyEg52wpxf4REKHmuLCb0aTE0hgRlz/NgNToYT4qIcNA7ng9b6UkdwnK5b4XKHMfE7g2sUbSrWPv88V3Pk7t7RWSxSDqHYQwXqbxPIu3CYouIgrSwxWUcztw1sK/gIeFjolfbd04TRfZyDHMpDeoLtujPZlZ+I/YksHA9b+4dct3TAUZ16nurMTaziGEtahVFoUuVCCJNKhCvdZlmU4SmvuLcye21kXz49+vIchNep3Bjya70IkwfKgfNQ2DUvBam+6pMY4ZFu0iTaMdAH8aB+q+ROfP/LF5GgRp8aTwzPwtKvfgpQF22sCAAA="
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "CdkFargateStack/CDKMetadata/Default"
      },
      "Condition": "CDKMetadataAvailable"
    }
  },
```

---

**TEST**

I am checking the log in in aws web console.

```
Cluster > AdminCluster > service: CdkFargateStack-ServiceD69D759B-cYrAHaRDN4mF
```

in `event` tab,

There are log like this

[image]

Service tries to start the task every one minutes.

---

**TEST**

ECS supports `docker-compose` style deployment.

So I try this with same image, then it works well

```
$docker context ls 
default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                          swarm
desktop-linux       moby                                                          unix:///Users/whitebear/.docker/run/docker.sock                         
docker-lamp-ecs     ecs 

$docker context use docker-lamp-ecs

$docker compose docker-compose.yml up
```

this deployment finished correctly container starts on `ECS`

However it fails in CDK.

---

**SOLUTION**

I found out the solution.

This could work

```
const adminRepo = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryArn(this, 'AdminRepository', 'arn:aws:ecr:ap-northeast-1:678100XXXXXX:repository/st_admin_site')
const adminImage = ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(adminRepo,"latest");
```

The previous code,

```
const adminImage = ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('st_admin_site:latest')
```

it doesn't mean to get my ecrRepository....

I use `ARN` instead.

This is stupid mistakes.

However there is not the way to get the log.

So it takes long time to find out.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It isn't clear

Comment: Does your image run correctly if you run it without `bash`? IIRC you can get stuck creating a service if it fails to start.

Comment: I try without bash  `docker run -p 8011:8011 -it st_admin_site:latest` it also works, I can access the server in container from browser.

Answer (score 1):

I had some stacks that took more than 30 minutes in the past :D How long were you waiting ?

What was the resources part looking ? What was already created, what was still "in action" :) ?

Did something crashed while creating and was in multiple retries ?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I went to bed and next morning. it rollbacks with message `4:58:12 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ECS::Service                         | ServiceD69D759B
Resource timed out waiting for completion (RequestToken: 0281c947-d44e-e653-79dc-7327140d850d)` Now I can start from new point to debug.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Not much information to really know what's happening, but IIRC if your container fails to start it will fail to create the ECS service. You can check if the service was actually created in the ECS console, and if it exists, check the event log to see if they aren't failing. If they are failing, you can check the reason in the task.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I can check the `event` in web UI console and updated the article